# bash printing and incrementing array values

Tags: linux, arrays, bash, printing, sh

I'm making a bash script in which I need to print a number while it's incremented like this:

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
```

I have made this but is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
pass[0]=0
pass[1]=0
pass[2]=0
pass[3]=0
for i in $(seq 1 9)
    pass[3]="$i"
    echo ${pass[*]}
done
```

I paste the script on cli and i get this.

```
$ ~ #!/bin/bash
$ ~ i=0
$ ~ pass[0]=0
$ ~ pass[1]=0
$ ~ pass[2]=0
$ ~ pass[3]=0
$ ~ for i in $(seq 1 9)
>     pass[3]="$i"
bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `pass[3]="$i"'
$ ~     echo ${pass[*]}
0 0 0 0
$ ~ done
bash: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `done'
$ ~
```

Comment: Do the values have to be in an array or can you just generate them as needed?

Comment: Your `for i in ...` is missing the corresponding `do` - e.g. `for i in $(seq 1 9); do pass[3]="$i"; done`

Comment: there are many ways to accomplish this task, but to make the least changes and answer what is wrong with your code, you forgot 'do' after the for expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this pure bash script:

```
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
   printf "%04d\n" $i
one
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
```

Comment: +1 but one can also do `for i in {1..10}; do printf "%04d\n" $i; done`.  Not sure which style of for-loop is better; I just like expansion.

Comment: @RayToal: I just prefer `for ((i=0; i<10; i++));` because it also accepts variable like `N=10; for ((i=0; i<N; i++));` as well.

Comment: Yes definitely more flexible in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
pass[0]=0
pass[1]=0
pass[2]=0
pass[3]=0
for i in $(seq 1 9)
do
    pass[3]="$i"
    echo ${pass[*]}
done
```

did you forget 'do'

Comment: That's a very inefficient way of doing it. Prefer anubhava's answer.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf as do I. but I was addressing why his sample code was not working. He had excluded the `do`

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who like expansions, you can also do:

```
printf "%s\n" {0001..0009}
```

or

```
printf "%.4d\n" {1..9}
```

No loop!

You can store in an array thus:

```
$ myarray=( {0001..0009} )
$ printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}"
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
$ echo "${myarray[3]}"
0004
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the formatting with `seq`:

```
seq -w 0000 0010
```

(if you don't like the `{0000..0010}` notation, which is more efficient but doesn't allow parameter substitution.)